# How to control displacement map applied by texture coordinate with object for cylindrical surface

Tags: shaders, bump

Any idea how to fix the shader to display the displacement map correctly (pictures A, B, C and D)? I am using texture coordinate with object (empty axis). It worked fine with a flat surface with unrepeatable configuration. But with a repeating pattern and a cylindrical surface, I did not reach the expected result.

Note: I tried other methods like sculpting with alpha texture and texture painting but the result is not sharp and clean when compared to shader including poly. count as well.

Picture - (A): Target Area
[image]

Picture - (B): End Result
[image]

Picture - (C): UV
[image]

Picture - (D): UV for Target Area
[image]

Source File:
[image]

Comment: how did u unwrap your uv? maybe it would be helpful to provide blend file so we don't have to ask....

Comment: Hi Chris, I added a picture for the UV above (picture - C) and (picture D) for target area. Unfortunately, there is no upload option for blend file.

Comment: there is, just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: If you are using UV mapping, you would expect to use the 'UV' texture coordinate, not the 'Object' texture coordinate..

Comment: Hi Robin, I am using Object indeed to avoid bump texture preparation.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the website. I uploaded the file and updated the post accordingly

Comment: Hi :). @Robin is right, the stretching is caused by using Object coordinates. No matter how you unwrap it, object coordinates ignore your UV map.